# Converting .csv (.geo column in sf package) to shapefile in r

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, r-sf

I have extracted values from raster layers and now want to convert it to shapefile. The csv file contains values of different bands and one column .geo in sf package. Any ideas to convert the csv file to shapefile in R.

```r
library(sf)
# Read data file
LS2013<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/Rice-Paper/master/LS_2013.csv",header = T)
head(LS2013)
.geo
1  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.0283799940066,21.191342664375124]}
2  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.02664540369682,21.19108403651402]}
3 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.02693524526529,21.191084036514017]}
4  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.02722508683375,21.19107957741297]}
5  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.02751492840221,21.19107957741297]}
6  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.02780031086967,21.19107511831191]}
```

The shapefile can be in geographic coordinate system (4326).

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use `sf::st_read(file.csv, crs = 4326)` rather than `read.csv`. Could you give details ?

Comment: Thanks. I extracted values from raster in GEE and exported it to Google Drive as csv file.

Comment: Does it work using `sf::st_read` because it looks more like a (geo)JSON file than a csv ? `sf::st_read` works well with JSON files

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I solved it

Comment: Cool ! I put this as an answer, would you mind accepting it ? (see [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file is a `JSON` or `geoJSON` file. You can directly use `sf::st_read`:

```r
sf::st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/Rice-Paper/master/LS_2013.csv", crs = 4326)
```